# Squaring numbers in consecutive order 0-9

Tags: c++

I am extremely new to the coding world. I just have a basic question regarding this function that squares integers from 0-9. I understand most of what's going on until I get to

```cpp
std::cout << i << "   " << square << "\n";
i = i + 1;
```

I'm not too sure how that ends up causing the output to square the results in order from 0-9. Can someone explain the reasoning behind this line of code? Here is the code for this function.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  
  int i = 0;
  int square = 0;
  
  while ( i <= 9) {
    square = i*i;
    std::cout << i << "     " << square << "\n";
    i = i + 1; 
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You state that you understand these two lines `while ( i <= 9) { square = i*i;`. Please explain them in your words, so that we can narrow down your misunderstandings or gaps of understanding.

Comment: I get that we are trying to square integers. square is an assigned variable and i is an int type.  Although, I'm not too sure I remember why they set int i and int square = to 0. Like I said i'm under the impression square is a variable to store information regarding i when we set square = to i * i which is i squared.  However, I don't understand why we use i = i + 1;  Is it a way to manipulate the data to give the correct output for integers squared from 0 to 9??? I also understand while is a conditonal loop that only keeps executing if the conditionals are true as well. After that, I'm lost.

Comment: while ( i <= 9) means that the function will keep executing if i is equal to or less than 9. Which makes sense to me when trying to find the results of squared numbers 0 to 9

Comment: I suspect that your main misunderstanding is that "i= i +1" and "square = i * i" are equations. Do you know the difference between a math equation and an assignment statement?

Comment: I do not know the difference, no sorry!

Comment: I have added an answer to elaborate this part of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```cpp
std::cout << i << "   " << square << "\n";
i = i + 1;
```

Doesn't square anything. It is merely outputting the current square that has *already* been calculated, and then increments `i` for the next loop iteration.

The actual squaring happens here:

```cpp
square = i*i;
```

So, the code starts at `i=0`, calculates `square=0*0` and displays it, then sets `i=1`, calculates `square=1*1` and displays it, then sets `i=2`, calculates `square=2*2` and displays it, and so on until `i` exceeds `9`, then the loop stops.

Answer (score 2):

- `std::cout << i << " " << square << "\n";` prints every
  number `i` next to its square, which is previously computed
  (`square = i*i;`).
- `i = i + 1;` increments `i` to compute the next square. It stops when `i` reaches `10`.

The output will look like this:

```
0 0
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 36
7 49
8 64
9 81
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help! You guys broke it down in detail wonderfully! Excited to keep adventuring on this path! Have a great day all! Again, thank you so much.

Comment: `square` is not the "square root". It is `i` squared. No root, rather `i` is the square root of `square`

Comment: Yes, it is the "square", not the "square root". Thanks, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start from beginning and what is happening, I will ignore first several lines and start at:

```
int i = 0;
int square = 0;
```

You see when you say `int i;` your compiler says I need to allocate bucket of memory to hold value for `i`. When you say `i = 0` zero is put into that memory bucket. That is what is happening for `square` as well.

Now to loop

```
while ( i <= 9 ) {
    square = i*i;
    std::cout << i << "     " << square << "\n";
    i = i + 1; 
}
```

So, lets ignore

```
square = i*i;
std::cout << i << "     " << square << "\n";
```

for now we will come to it later.

So

```
while ( i <= 9 ) {
    i = i + 1; 
}
```

goes into the loop and gets value from `i`'s bucket, adds `1` and puts new value into the `i`'s bucket. So in first loop it will be `i = 0 + 1`, put `1` into `i` bucket. Second, `i = 1 + 1` put `2` in, third `i = 2 + 1` put `3`.

So lets go back to `square` and its bucket.

```
square = i*i;
```

So first time we go into the loop `i = 0` and `square = 0 * 0` so compiler puts `0` into `square`'s memory bucket. Next time it hits `square` `i` has been incremented to `1` so `square = 1 * 1`, thus compiler puts `1` into the bucket. Third time `i` is `2` so `square = 2 * 2`, and compiler puts `4` into the bucket. And so on till it `i <= 9`. When `i` hits `10` loop is not executed.

Answer (score 2):

In comments you have stated that you do not know the difference between a math equation and an assignment statement. You are not alone.
I will try to explain, as an addition to existing answers, to provide a different angle.

First, two examples of math equations:

```
     x = 1 +1
   y+1 = x*2
```

To illustrate their meaning, let me point our that you first can determine that x is 2 and in a second step that y is 3.

Now examples of assignment statements.

```
x = 1 +1;
y = x*2;
```

The minor difference is the `;` at the end, tipping you off that it is a program code line.

Here the first one looks pretty much the same as the first equation example. But for a C compiler this is different. It is a command, requesting that the program, when executing this line, assigns the value 2 to the variable x.

The second assingment statement I made similar to the second equation example, but importantly different, because the left side of `=` is not an expression, not something to calculate. The equation-turned-statement

```
y +1 = x*2;
```

does not work, the compiler will complain that it cannot assign a value (no problem with doing a little calculation on the right side) to an expression. It cannot assign the value 4 to the expression `y+1`.

This helps with your problem, because you need to understand that both lines

```
i = i + 1;
square = i*i;
```

are statements which, when executed (and only then) cause a change to the value of the variable in that line.
Your program starts off with the value 0 in the variable `i`. At some point it executes the first of the statements above, causing the value of `i` to change from 0 to 1. Later, when the same line is executed again, the value of `i` changes from 1 to 2. So the values of `i` change, loop iteration by loop iteration, to 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

The second assignment line causes the value of `square` to become the value of `i`, whatever it is during that loop iteration and multiplied by itself. I.e. it gets to be 4,9,16,25,36....

Outputting the value of `square` each time in the loop gets you the squares.
Since you state that you basically understand loops, I just mention that the loop ends when `i` is not lower or equal to 9 any more.

Now from the other point of view.
If you try to solve the equation

```
i = i + 1
```

for `i`, you should hear your math teacher groaning.
You can subtract `i` from both sides and get

```
0 = 1
```

The solution is "Don't try.", it is not an equation.

Comment: I wouldnt pick on the `;` as a significant difference. As a contrived example `if (x = foo()) { ...` doesn't need a `;` to not be a maths equation. Maybe this could benefit from a word or two on expressions vs statements. Otherwise I like this approach of detailing the difference between maths equations and code.

Answer (score 1):

So we have a while loop here, which run while `i <= 9`. The square of any number `i` is `i * i`.

```
while(i <=9){ //check the condition and then enter the body
 //body 
 }
```

But we need a condition to get out of the loop, otherwise our program will enter into an infinite loop.

To ensure, we will exit from the loop we increase the value of `i` by 1.

so at first when `i = 0` `square = 0 * 0 = 0`,now we increase the value of `i` i.e now `i` becomes one which still satisfies the condition to stay inside the loop , again it will calculate `square = 1 * 1` until and unless the value of `i` remains less than or equal to 9.

Once the condition fails, the execution comes out of the loop.